# Handlebars is failing to render identical templates

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars.js to render two templates, both completely identical bar a different ID. The first render is not functional (No list rendered) but the second renders perfectly. What could explain this?
HTML:

```
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Src</label>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" onChange="takeSelectedSourceValue(this);">
              <option id="source-language" value="" selected disabled>Auto</option>
            </select>
          
            <script type="text/handlebar-template" id="selectPersonTemplate">
              {{#each people}}
                <option value="{{valueLang}}">{{htmlLang}}</option>
              {{/each}}
            </script>
            </select>
          </div>
          
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Src</label>
              </div>
              <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02" onChange="takeSelectedSourceValue(this);">
                <option id="source-language" value="" selected disabled>Auto</option>
              </select>
            
              <script type="text/handlebar-template" id="selectPersonTemplate">
                  {{#each people}}
                    <option value="{{valueLang}}">{{htmlLang}}</option>
                  {{/each}}
                </script>
              </select>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
  var people = [
    { valueLang: 'DE', htmlLang: 'DE' },
    { valueLang: 'FR', htmlLang: 'FR' },
    { valueLang: 'IT', htmlLang: 'IT' },
    { valueLang: 'ES', htmlLang: 'ES' },
    { valueLang: 'SV', htmlLang: 'SV' },
    { valueLang: 'DA', htmlLang: 'DA' }
  ];
  
  var templateText = $("#selectPersonTemplate").html();
  
  var selectPersonTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateText);
  
  var html = selectPersonTemplate({ people: people });
  
  $("#inputGroupSelect01").html(html);
  $("#inputGroupSelect02").html(html);
});
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding the purpose of templates. You do not want to define the same template twice - `#selectPersonTemplate`. You want to define it once - ie., have a single script tag with `id=selectPersonTemplate`. However, I don't see any reason why both of your `<select>` menus would not get populated with the value of `html`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/38k7xurq/

Comment: @76484 Okay, yes I get your meaning re single templates. I also don't understand what is really happening with Handlebars, for example, if I render the template only once, I still have the same issue (handlebars doesn't load the list, only allowing the hardcoded 'auto' value, but if i add a second repetition of handlebars, it loads. Please see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6w9rzoka/

Comment: You need to include the Handlebars library and jQuery because your code has dependencies on both of those. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/175xg2vc/ - where I haven't changed any code, but have imported both libraries.